# Lenovo Y520 laptop dual boot Ubuntu 18.04/Windows 10 installation problems continued

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, lenovo, windows-10, freeze

Following up from my first question on 18.04 installation. I found a thread about setting up AHCI for SATA SSD on a Dell machine and thought it might apply.

The HW: Lenovo Y520, i7 7700, 16GB RAM. NVMe SSD 500GB, + Samsung 850 SATA SSD 500 GB

The flow:

1. Setup boot to safe mode in Windows (msconfig).
2. Boot to safe mode, change SATA controller mode to AHCI .
3. Boot to safe mode again, and disable safe mode boot (msconfig again).
4. Boot again to Windows, it worked! Now NVMe SSD drive with Windows 10 boot is found and starts up just fine.

Now the machine boots to windows  drive (original NVMe with windows10 install). OK, now install Ubuntu 18.04 again on the SATA ssd I added. The install still did not give the "Install alongside Windows" option, so I reinstalled Ubuntu and let it erase the drive and setup partitions. Now grub works on cold startup, and I can select boot with Windows 10 or boot to Ubuntu.

Unfortunately, the behavior in Ubuntu is nearly identical to what is was before. It just freezes and requires a hard reset regardless of anything attempted. Yes, wifi works now. Additionally the fan just goes full on the whole time. I'm reading some disturbing threads now about Ubuntu on laptops and problems with power control? Can somebody please suggest anything to try now? Maybe reformat the new SSD again and try another install from USB drive? Good progress tonight, Ubuntu still does not function though. I'm trying to be persistent, but I'm getting tired. Fedora?

Here is additional information. When this system is booted from Ubuntu flash drive (the one I've been trying to install from), Ubuntu seems to be operating OK. No freeze or lock ups. Firefox operates, Gparted works, terminal io all function.